# Was Goku using his full power against Kale?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super episode 100,

> Goku attacked Kale Super Saiyan green "berserker" mode with a Kamehameha in Super Saiyan blue.

Was Goku using his full power when he did it?  If so, does this mean that...

> Super Saiyan green "berserker" is more powerful than Super Saiyan blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goku states when he goes SSJB that he's going to use "a little more power" (when I return home tonight I'll get the timestamp).

My take from this comment is that he did not go all out.

The only times he has gone all out, he also uses Kaioken in his SSJB form. Until we see him do so, I'd suggest he's holding back on power.

Edit: He actually says "Let out more power" at 17:38 of Episode 100. This is still useful as "more" is less than "most" or "all".

As to your second question, I'd say that this LSSJ (as was the name for it with Broly, which this is an homage to) transformation, cannot yet to be claimed to be stronger than SSJB. Yes, Kale walked straight through a SSJB Kamehameha, but she was completely taken out by Jiren from Universe 11 - admittedly she wasn't prepared for that hit, but it didn't look like Jiren was trying either. Once we see how Goku fighting serious fares against Jiren fighting serious, we can get an idea of how LSSJ and SSJB stack up.

Comment: yes that's important to keep in mind, I didnt realize about that detail, thanks!

Comment: btw, I meant going all out in Blue, not counting kaioken. We know he can give more with kaioken

Comment: The battle between the Kale and Goku was much similar to the battle between Goku and Broly

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I agree and don't think this was a mistake. If you go back to the first film you see they capture all the best parts: "no-selling" a Kamehameha; dragging Goku by his face through rubble; Vegeta claiming it to be the true form of Saiyans; the "colour-shift" on charging up the green energy blast. More too, but I'd have to go back to the Broly film to remember them. As an homage to Broly, I loved it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Remember, it's a battle royal so he has to conserve his power for the long haul and you can't kill anyone. So the Kamehameha that was launched at Kale wasn't meant to kill, at most probably push her back but that didn't work...

Comment: So no I don't believe SSB Kale is stronger than SSB Goku, but under these circumstances than yeah because kale has no control of her powers as weall as stated by piccolo

Comment: Those are very valid points, but he didnt make it a single scratch!